# how to truncate long xticks text in python plotly?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I have a problem with long xticks text.
this my code.

```
fig = px.bar(dataa)
fig.update_layout(yaxis_title="Owners_Jurisdiction Count", xaxis_title="Owners")
fig.update_xaxes(tickangle=45, showgrid=True)
fig.show()
```

but what i got is the below picture:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBAxJ.png)

I want all long xticks text are truncated to 7 characters(for example)

Answer (score 0):

This question has been asked a few times before:

[How to shorten and show only a part of text in plotly express axis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66505485/how-to-shorten-and-show-only-a-part-of-text-in-plotly-express-axis)

[Is it possible to limit or truncate the characters of the tick label in plotly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66504218/is-it-possible-to-limit-or-truncate-the-characters-of-the-tick-label-in-plotly)

Answer from first post:

`To shorten the tick labels of your x-axis, you could either change the id's of your column beforehand by changing the dataframe, or you could use .update_layout() to change your tick labels afterwards.`

Comment: In python link, the code reverse all xticks names. how can i solve it?

Answer (score 0):

If the question is how to shorten the x-axis string to 7 characters because it is long, the x-axis ticks can be updated after drawing, so the list is set up using comprehension notation.

```
fig = px.bar(dataa)
fig.update_layout(yaxis_title="Owners_Jurisdiction Count", xaxis_title="Owners")
fig.update_traces(x=[x[:7] for x in df['Owners_name']])
fig.update_xaxes(tickangle=45, showgrid=True)
fig.show()
```